# How to collapse all methods in Embarcadero Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi-2010

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> unfolds all the collapsed methods, but I couldn't find a way to fold all methods in the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Delphi Wikia site:

[Default IDE Shortcut Keys](https://delphi.fandom.com/wiki/Default_IDE_Shortcut_Keys)

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
>   Toggles Code folding between On and Off
>   Delphi 2006 and up
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
>   Code folding: Expands All blocks of code
>   Delphi 2006 and up
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
>   Code folding: Collapse current block of code
>   Delphi 2006 and up
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
>   Code folding: Expand current block of code
>   Delphi 2006 and up
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
>   Code folding: Toggle Current block (expand & collapse)
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
>   Code folding: Collapses all regions {$region 'comment'}..{$endregion}
>   Delphi 2006 and up
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
>   Code folding: Collapse nested procedures
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
>   Code folding: Collapse all methods
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
>   Code folding: Collapse all classes
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
>   Code folding: Collapses down to primary Groups [Interface/Implementation]
>   Delphi 2006 and up
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
>   Code folding: Collapses Namespace/Unit
>   Delphi 2006 and up